# Is it more efficient to put the 'new' in the put method, or use an intermediate variable?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

Which of the below ways of adding to a HashMap is more efficient (considering both time and space efficiency)?

Way 1:

```
Music foo = new Music(Files.getMusic("bar/bold.mp3"));
HashMap.put("rock", foo);
```

Way 2:

```
HashMap.put("rock", new Music(Files.getMusic("bar/bold.mp3")));
```

Comment: Identical.  Local "temporary" variables are essentially "free" in Java.  So the first sequence is preferred because it's easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the exact same. When running

```
new Music(Files.getMusic("bar/bold.mp3"));
```

You create an object in memory, and return a reference to it. Whether you temporarily store that reference in `foo` before passing it to the `HashMap` or not doesn't really make a difference (and even if it would, this would be optimized away).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) will be accepted in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

this is identical.
Java objects are passed by reference, you have the exact same number of objects created in both cases.

Comment: Fix "pass by reference" and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: I'll keep my personal opinion to myself, but [it's generally accepted that Java is pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).